# Load data in cache with java

Tags: java, hibernate, browser-cache, ehcache

I´m a little lost with a problem. I need to save in cache a list of data which I query from the Database. The list is very big and when it loads in a combobox isn´t optim. Any ideas about this?

My code is:

- Controller:

  ```
  model.addAttribute(LISTA_LUGARES,lugarService.findLugaresByIdMunicipio(documentacionDTO.getIdMunicipio()));
  ```
- Service:

  ```
  public List<Lugar> findLugaresByIdMunicipio(Long idMunicipio) {
      return this.lugarRepository.findLugaresByIdMunicipio(idMunicipio);
  }
  ```
- Repository:

  ```
  @Query("from Lugar l where l.municipio.id = :idMunicipio order by l.nombre asc")
  List<Lugar> findLugaresByIdMunicipio(@Param("idMunicipio") Long idMunicipio);
  ```
- HTML:

  ```
   <select
      id="lugar" th:field="*{idLugar}" class="form-control">
      <option th:each="type : ${lugar}" th:value="${type.id}"
      th:text="#{${type.nombre}}">opciones</option>
      </select>
  ```

Comment: What does it mean `not optim`?

Comment: Bad performance, the list loads slow. Sorry, my english is very bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like **EhCache** to set the query as `@Cacheable`, this will  indicate that the result of invoking a method (or all methods in a class) can be cached.

Each time an advised method is invoked, the caching behavior will be applied, checking whether the method was already invoked for the given arguments:

[Here's an example](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-hibernate-ehcache-caching)